# What is the best projection to use for this?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, united-states

I have two vector layers of state and county boundaries that I would like to find the areas for each individual state/county. However, the CRS is set to `NAD83` with `EPSG:4269`. Due to this, when I look at the `Attribute Table`, `ALAND` is waaay too big to make sense and there are no units. I think that these are in arcsecs, and someone recommended at [What are units for calculated area in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254763) that I change the CRS to UTM or Lambert.

Are there any recommendations for a CRS that would fit both the U.S. and counties shapefiles (they are overlaid so I don't want them to look offset)?

Comment: You've got multiple questions (*too broad*) and you're soliciting opinions (*opinion-based*). Please take the [Tour] to better understand how GIS SE operates.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `US National Atlas Equal Area` [EPSG:2163](http://epsg.io/2163) which is in metres if you are working with the whole of the USA. For any one state you should probably use one of the State Plane projections that applies to that state.